# Can we mark unwanted default fields in pre-built models in Microsoft AI builder as "Not available in document/collection"?

Tags: power-automate

I'm using a pre-built model of Microsoft AI builder for document processing (Invoices). In this pre-built model there are around 30 fields which are defined as default, but I need only 10 out of them. There is no option to remove the unwanted fields. If I mark these unwanted fields as "Not available in collection" when tagging, will this impact negatively on the performance of the model?

I'm trying to mark them as "Not available in collection" and move forward